# Select from another table within an Insert Trigger

Tags: sql-server-2005, triggers

I am maintaining an audit table, where in I have a parent table and it's child table.I want to insert the primary key of the parent audit table into it's child audit table.
Should I be declaring a **"before insert"** instead of a **"for insert"** trigger. Here's my code:

```
CREATE trigger [trgAudtblChild] On [tblChild]
for Insert 
as
BEGIN

declare @serNo  bigint 
declare @expSerNo  int 
declare @postPercent  numeric  (12, 2) 
declare @prdSAPid  varchar  (50) 
declare @lastUpdatedBy  int 
declare @lastUpdatedOn  smalldatetime 

SELECT 
 --@serno = serno,
 @expSerNo = expSerNo ,
 @postPercent = postPercent ,
 @prdSAPid = prdSAPid ,
 @lastUpdatedBy = lastUpdatedBy ,
 @lastUpdatedOn = lastUpdatedOn
FROM INSERTED

select @serno = max(at_serno) from AT_tblParent

insert into AT_tblChild(serNo, expSerNo, postPercent
                       , prdSAPid, lastUpdatedBy, lastUpdatedOn
                       , change_column_index) values(
                                  @serNo, @expSerNo, @postPercent
                          , @prdSAPid, @lastUpdatedBy, @lastUpdatedOn
                          , 'INSERTED')

End
Return
```

The above code, does not work and puts the table into transaction.

Comment: Why do you change primary key on the fly? Audit table should have the same key as original one, otherwise how would you pair them? Furthermore, nobody guaranteees that another record will not be inserted into parent BEFORE you get the chance to get max(at_serno), and you will end up with wrongly linked records. Also never ever assume that inserted contains one record only - this might be true ATM but you are setting up nasty surprise to future you. And, there is no before trigger in Sql Server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**<kbd>Before Trigger</kbd>** - When you want to Intercept the data before it actually gets Inserted in Table.

**<kbd>For Trigger</kbd>** - Your record is Inserted but can still modify it.

The only difference is that about record is actually Inserted or not.

### Back to the original Query

In you above mentioned situation, you should not use <kbd>Before Trigger</kbd>. Consider a case, when your Parent Table record Insertion in under some Transaction and same Transaction gets Rollbacked. In that case, It will crash for the Foreign key constraint. Because you will try to Reference a Foreign key Record of Parent Table into Child Table during Insertion which does not exist in Parent Table.